# How to make a document compile into two different orders of its parts?

Tags: compiling, literate-programming

I want to set up a diary that compiles in two different orders: One is work by day, the other is work by project according to tags I give to the particular chunks of work I did each day.

For example, I write my diary as usual in work by day form:

```
2/2/15

-- bought a new screwdriver (tag: car maintainence) 

-- scetched my plan for world domination (tag: world domination)

3/4/15

-- started studying physics (tag: world domination)

-- finished tax declaraction (tag: burocracy)
```

Compiling by project would yield tags as sections:

```
car maintainence  

-- 2/2/15: bought a new screwdriver

world domination

-- 2/2/15: scetched my plan for world domination

-- 3/4/15: started studying physics

burocracy

-- 3/4/15: finished tax declaraction
```

I know this is pretty close to the literal programming paradigm the whole LaTex documentation follows: A code chunks in a document can be compiled to two different orders: For human understanding and for use by the machine. However, I want two human readable versions --say pdf-files-- as output. Is there some package that helps?

Comment: For me the solution is answers package http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/answers  but may be there is others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. I make it only with 2 tags but you can add more

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifbytag

%-------------- here we make the chice by tag or by date (if false)
\bytagtrue
%\bytagfalse

\newcommand{\cartag}{car maintainence} % may one add formatting : bold, space ...
\newcommand{\worldtag}{world domination} % may one add formatting

\makeatletter
\ifbytag
\newcommand{\mtdate}[1]{%
\g@addto@macro\cartag{\par #1}%
\g@addto@macro\worldtag{\par #1}}
\newcommand{\mtcar}[1]{%
\g@addto@macro\cartag{\par -- #1}}
\newcommand{\mtworld}[1]{%
\g@addto@macro\worldtag{\par -- #1}}
\else
\newcommand{\mtdate}[1]{\par #1}
\newcommand{\mtcar}[1]{\par -- #1 (tag: car maintainence)}
\newcommand{\mtworld}[1]{\par -- #1 (tag: world domination)}
\let\cartag\empty\let\worldtag\empty
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mtdate{2/2/15}

\mtcar{bought a new  screwdriver} 

\mtworld{scetched my plan for world domination}

\mtdate{3/4/15}

\mtworld{started studying physics}

\mtcar{finished tax declaraction}

%--------------------------here we print tages if by tag
\cartag

\worldtag
\end{document}
```