# How to compile the document in particular orders?

Tags: macros

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\reflog}[2]{\cleardoublepage    ref log --~#1 \\ #2}
\newcommand{\obsform}[2]{\cleardoublepage   obs form --~#1 \\ #2}
\newcommand{\lessonplan}[2]{\cleardoublepage lesson plan--~#1 \\ #2}


\begin{document}

\reflog{01 July 2015}{test test test test test }
\lessonplan{01 July 2015}{test test test test test }


\obsform{02 July 2015}{test test test test test }

\reflog{03 July 2015}{test test test test test }

\lessonplan{04 July 2015}{test test test test test }
\reflog{04 July 2015}{test test test test test }


\lessonplan{05 July 2015}{test test test test test }


\end{document}
```

If I just compile the document, it gives them in the exact order as I input them.
Is there a way to say compile them according to the commands?

Say compile all `\reflog`s first, then `\obsform`s and then `\lessonplan`?
But I still want to be able to disable this easily. So it's like an off/on switch control.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The [TeXBook](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook?lang=en) is the main source of information about how TeX interprets, not compiles, TeX documents. Since LaTeX is built on top of Tex this means the TeXBook is relevant.

Comment: you can see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238208/how-to-make-a-document-compile-into-two-different-orders-of-its-parts/